# how i can create boundingbox area using mapbox api

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bounding-box, mapbox

hi i m new in iphone development some can help me to cache some area using `mapbox framework`
here is the guideline for this

You want to use the `RMTileCacheBackgroundDelegate` protocol for this. Just specify a bounding box and region on your

```
mapView.tileCache
```

and it will start working.

question is how to use `protocol` and how to create bounding box

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you done so far?? Provide a solution and People will help...

Answer (score -1):

I provided that answer via the MapBox support forums. You will need to learn Cocoa from Apple's developer documentation. Learn what protocols are or else you will not be able to create iOS applications. Pasting a code example here when you have tried nothing will not help.